# accessing data from application.properties inside an interface

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I want to limit the results of some queries

**application.properties**

```
...
spring.neo4j.resultlimit=10
...
```

**PersonRepository**

```
public interface PersonRepository extends GraphRepository<Person> {

    @Query("MATCH p=()-->() RETURN nodes(p) as n, relationships(p)[0] as e") //<--how can I access spring.neo4j.resultlimit value and limits this query?
    Iterable<Map<String, String>> graph();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Spring client can get the value of `spring.neo4j.resultlimit` and pass that to the `graph()` method, which can be defined like this:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends GraphRepository<Person> {
    @Query("MATCH p=()-->() RETURN nodes(p) as n, relationships(p)[0] as e LIMIT {0}")
    Iterable<Map<String, String>> graph(Integer resultLimit);
}
```

Comment: yeah I want to avoid this pervasive change if possible (I have to change a lot of methods)..there is no way to read that value straight in the interface?